# c++ set erase function not working properly with iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, set

```cpp
set<int> s = {1, 2, 3, 4};
auto it = s.begin();
while (it != s.end()) {
    // this correct 
    s.erase(it++);
    
    // this incorrect 
    s.erase(it);
    it++;
}
```

why on top of code can running?

My understand of the order when my code running is:

1. When the erase function is executed, then iterator was deleted.
2. The chaotic iterators executing add, it behaviour is undefined.

But it running normal, So my problem is why it can running and these code have difference?

Comment: This is in the doc: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated.

It's just undefined behaviour, it might work, it might not, who knows^^

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude why? It is going to work as expected.

Comment: @SergeyA Will `s.erase(it++)` be evaluated as `s.erase(it); it = it + 1;` or `auto temp = it; it = it + 1; s.erase(temp)`? Is it well defined?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, I believe it will be evaluated similar to your second scenario, and I am quite certain it is going to be well-defined. Post-fix increment returns the value of the original operand, so this is what will be erased - but `it` would already be incremented.

Comment: @SergeyA It seems you're correct: "... every value computation *and side effect* associated with any argument expression ...  is sequenced before execution of every expression or statement in the body of the called function" (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yep, absolutely. Otherwise the behavior would be quite counter-intuitive (not that it ever stopped C++ standard from imposing behavior requirements, I admit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way would be:

```
it = s.erase(it);
```

Your code with post-increment also works, but it is less transparent. To recall, post-increment version is semantically equivalent with the following snippet:

```
temp = it;
++it;
s.erase(temp);
```

As for your claims of ill-formed (second version) code "running", the code which has undefined behavior can be "running" or even seem to deliver expected results. This is the gist of undefined behavior. And the code which increments iterator which has been erased exhibits undefined behavior, as per `std::set::erase` [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase):

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other
> references and iterators are not affected

Comment: So the executing result of these undefined behavior was decied compiler?

Comment: @LYFer some time compiler makes certain decisions in present of undefined behavior, sometimes it does not, and just generates code which would execute with unpredictable results.